# How can I convert scrollIntoView with smooth animation to a Promise?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to `scrollIntoView` a particular element smoothly and then do something.

Example

```
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}).then(() => {
    // Do something here
})
```

**I know that it can't be done this way** as native `scrollIntoView` doesn't return a Promise. But, how do I achieve something like this?

I'm using Angular 7 BTW. So if there are any directives that could help me achieve this, it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with prototypes, I think this could be a solution to your problem without download any npm packages

```js
/* Extends Element Objects with a function named scrollIntoViewPromise
*  options: the normal scrollIntoView options without any changes
*/

Element.prototype.scrollIntoViewPromise = function(options){

  // "this" refers to the current element (el.scrollIntoViewPromise(options): this = el)
  this.scrollIntoView(options);
  
  // I create a variable that can be read inside the returned object ({ then: f() }) to expose the current element 
  let parent = this;
  
  // I return an object with just a property inside called then
  // then contains a function which accept a function as parameter that will be execute when the scroll ends 
  return { 
    then: function(x){
      // Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API for more informations  
      const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        let [entry] = entries;
        
        // When the scroll ends (when our element is inside the screen)
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        
          // Execute the function into then parameter and stop observing the html element
          setTimeout(() => {x(); intersectionObserver.unobserve(parent)}, 100)
        }
      });
      
      // I start to observe the element where I scrolled 
      intersectionObserver.observe(parent);
    }
  };
}


element.scrollIntoViewPromise({behavior: "smooth"}).then(()=>console.log("EHI!"));
```

I've created an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-msigkc?file=index.js). I know it's not an angular application, but it's a good starting point. You just need to implement it (If you're using typescript you have to create an interface which extends Element with the new function).

Comment: I certainly wasn't able to understand what you said. Could you be more descriptive about the code that you have written?

Comment: I added some comments. Hope this new version could help. Tell me if you have any specific question.

Comment: @FedericoGalfione hi i got some issues here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56076337/8662236

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

One way you can solve this is by using [smooth-scroll-into-view-if-nedded](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smooth-scroll-into-view-if-needed?activeTab=readme) it actually return a promise so you can bind to it and apply your logic.

Comment: If it does what you say it'll be amazing. But I think 115kb is an overkill just for scroll.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idea how you may catch animation ending.
You may do it in vanilla JS with a 'scroll' event listener.
Check this example https://codepen.io/Floky87/pen/BEOYvN

```
var hiddenElement = document.getElementById("box");
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var isScrolling;

function handleScroll(event) {
  // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
  window.clearTimeout(isScrolling);

  // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
  isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {
    alert(1);
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, 66);
}

function handleButtonClick() {
  document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, false);
  hiddenElement.scrollIntoView({ block: "center", behavior: "smooth" });
}

btn.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);
```

Comment: Seems quite promising.

Answer (score 1):

I made it like this

```
const scrollIntoViewPromise = async (node: HTMLElement, options?: ScrollIntoViewOptions) => {
    node.scrollIntoView(options);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            const [entry] = entries;
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(true);
                    intersectionObserver.unobserve(node);
                }, 100);
            }
        });
        intersectionObserver.observe(node);
    });
};
```